# Modify Audit object acces policy

Tags: windows, batch, powershell, group-policy, local

I'm trying to automate this step on a local network that's not included in a domain. I've tried using auto-it but had little luck with that. Is there any way of doing this using a batch script or using PowerShell ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can create a template file that matches the security policy settings you wish to apply. This file can then be applied via the command line using a tool called secedit.

[This link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313434) provides the details.

Comment: I have reviewed your link, @zdan, but there is one thing I am not sure about it: can a template file for **secedit** make changes to only one parameter of the Security Policies? Or will the template change all the parameters on the section? Thanks.